# How can an address be same as a value?

Tags: c

Here is a sample code. I believe array is an address while *array is the value

```
int array[7][7];
 array == *array
```

But I found out array same as *array. How is it?

Comment: `array == *array` is a type error.

Comment: Prefer to use arrays with their natural operator `[]`: `array == array[0]` which is fully equivalent to your expression.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
int arr[7][7];
```

`arr` is *two dimensional array* containing *7 one dimensional array* & each one dimensional array contains 7 elements. It looks like

```
arr[0][0] arr[0][1] arr[0][2] arr[0][3] arr[0][4] arr[0][5] arr[0][6] arr[0][7]  
   |         |          |         |         |         |        |          |     | ....|
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------       -----
  (0x100)                           |                                              |
                                 arr[0] (0x100)                                   arr[1]   ... arr[6]
                                    |                                              |
                                    -----------------------------------------------
                                                          |
                                                         arr(0x100) -assume base address is 0x100
```

`arr`, `arr[0]` and address of `arr[0][0]` all results in same i.e `arr` and `*arr` results in same address.

Answer (score 1):

An element of a multidimensional array is an array, which in many cases decays to a pointer to its first element.

So, in both cases you have a pointer to the same location in memory.

As of C, they aren't technically the same, because they point to differents objects, but because those objects have the same address, and because most implementations store all pointers in the same format, they happen to evaluate equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a value without a type.

`123456789` just like that is nothing; you need to know if it's an integer, a double, a pointer, ...

So, I like to think of it as the pair `(value, type)`.
And that *value* could be `(123456789, int)`, or `(123456789, double)`, or `(123456789, char*)`, ... which are all different pairs (with the same value).

In your case you have `(<address>, char(*)[7])` **not the same as** `(<address>, char*)`